PlatformException(Unexpected security result code, Code: -25300
I am having this error after ios 17.5 update When I run my flutter app
PlatformException(Unexpected security result code, Code: -25300, Message: The specified item could not be found in the keychain., -25300, null), stack trace: #0      StandardMethodCodec.decodeEnvelope (package:flutter/src/services/message_codecs.dart:648:7)
#1      MethodChannel._invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:334:18)
<asynchronous suspension>
#2      checkAgreementIntroScreen (package:mobile/src/routing/check_agreement_intro_screen.dart:17:7)
<asynchronous suspension>
#3      FutureHandlerProviderElementMixin.handleFuture.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (package:riverpod/src/async_notifier/base.dart:348:9)
<asynchronous suspension>
flutter: error: PlatformException(Unexpected security result code, Code: -25300, Message: The specified item could not be found in the keychain., -25300, null), stack trace: #0      StandardMethodCodec.decodeEnvelope (package:flutter/src/services/message_codecs.dart:648:7)
#1      MethodChannel._invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:334:18)
<asynchronous suspension>
#2      checkAgreementIntroScreen (package:mobile/src/routing/intro_screen.dart:17:7)
<asynchronous suspension>
#3      FutureHandlerProviderElementMixin.handleFuture.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (package:riverpod/src/async_notifier/base.dart:348:9)
<asynchronous suspension>


I tried to print the keychain but I couldnt make it.

Fixed the error after rollback of FlutterSecureStorage as described here: https://github.com/mogol/flutter_secure_storage/issues/709

dart fix solved the problem. Looks like after the Flutter 3.2.2 update I needed it to do that.

I downgrade version to flutter_secure_storage: 9.0.0 and it helps

I fixed it using (flutter_secure_storage: ^9.2.2):
  IOSOptions iosOptions = const IOSOptions(
      accessibility: KeychainAccessibility.first_unlock_this_device);

Use these options on iOptions on methods read and delete:
storage.delete(
    key: key.name, iOptions: iosOptions);

This configuration did not work well on the readAll method.
Bonus: To replicate this bug locally You can create a method with the write, read, and delete method inside a while with at least 1000 repetitions.
